# The pdf of ancillary statistic of $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

$X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are independently and identically $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distributed. I want to find the UMVUE of $P(X \le c)$.

$T=({\bar X},S^2)$ is sufficient and complete for $(\mu,\sigma^2)$. It is easy to find an unbiased estimator $I(X_1 \le c)$, so the answer is $E(I(X_1 \le c) \mid T)$.

$A=\frac{X_1-{\bar X}}{S}$ is an ancillary statistic of $(\mu,\sigma^2)$, so it is independent of $T$.

$$\begin{align}
E(I(X_1 \le c) \mid T) & = P(X_1 \le c \mid T) \\
 & = P(A \le \frac{c-{\bar X}}{S} \mid T) \\ 
 & = P(A \le \frac{c-{\bar x}}{s}) \\
\end{align}$$

The question is what is the pdf of $A$.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181964/the-pdf-of-fracx-1-barxs. Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330264/distribution-of-fracx-1-barxs-when-x-1-ldots-x-n-are-i-i-d-n-mu.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you! I am a newbie and have not found the problem…

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4291109/321264