# Given IID normal random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, show that $(X_1 - \bar{X})/S$ is ancillary.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

This has been bugging me for the past day, and I just can't seem to figure it out.

Suppose $X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$ are IID, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma^2>0$ are unknown.

I want to show that $Z = \frac{X_1 - \bar{X}}{S}$ is an ancillary statistic (its distribution is independent of $\mu$ and $\sigma$). Basically, I need to calculate the distribution of $Z$.

I know that the formula for the density of $Z$ is given by (Shao, *Mathematical Statistics*, pg. 165 eq (3.1)):
$$
 f(z) = \frac{\sqrt{n}\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}(n-1)\Gamma(\frac{n-2}{2})} \bigg[ 1 - \frac{nz^2}{(n-1)^2}\bigg]^{(n/2) - 2} I_{(0, (n-1)/\sqrt{n})}(|z|)
$$
but I have no idea how to derive this result. Presumably you use some transformation, but I just can't seem to find the right one.

I don't need a full solution, mostly just some help getting started. Thanks! Oh, and $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$ are the sample mean and sample variance, respectively.

Comment: You can rewrite $Z$ as $$Z=\frac{\frac{X_1-\mu}{\sigma}-\frac{\overline X-\mu}{\sigma}}{S/\sigma}$$ to see that its distribution is free of $(\mu,\sigma)$. The distribution is derived here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181964/the-pdf-of-fracx-1-barxs.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to point out the connection of $Z$ with a $t$-distribution, which is apparent from the relationship of $Z$ with a correlation coefficient discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/182087).

I assume $S^2$ is defined as $$S^2=\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2$$

Then for $n>2$, the following has a $t$-distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom:

$$T=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}(X_1-\overline X)}{\sqrt{\left\{(n-1)S^2-\frac{n}{n-1}(X_1-\overline X)^2\right\}/(n-2)}} \sim t_{n-2} \tag{1}$$

In terms of $Z$, we have

$$T=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{n(n-2)}{n-1}}Z}{\sqrt{n-1-\frac{nZ^2}{n-1}}}$$

Or,

$$Z = \pm \frac{(n-1)T}{\sqrt{n(T^2+n-2)}}$$

Since $T$ and $-T$ have the same distribution, $Z$ has the following distribution for $n>2$:

$$Z \sim \frac{(n-1)t_{n-2}}{\sqrt{n(t^2_{n-2}+n-2)}} \tag{2}$$

---

To prove $(1)$, we can transform $\boldsymbol X \mapsto \boldsymbol Y$ such that $\boldsymbol Y=P \boldsymbol X$, where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix with its first two rows fixed as:

$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac1{\sqrt n} &\frac1{\sqrt n} &\cdots &\frac1{\sqrt n}\\
\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}} &\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}} &\cdots &\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}\\
\vdots & \vdots &\cdots & \vdots
\end{bmatrix}$$

This implies $Y_1=\sqrt n\overline X\,,\,Y_2=\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}(X_1-\overline X)$ and

$$(n-1)S^2-\frac{n}{n-1}(X_1-\overline X)^2=\sum_{i=3}^n Y_i^2\,,$$

so that

$$T=\frac{Y_2}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=3}^n Y_i^2/(n-2)}}$$

Note that $Y_2,Y_3,\ldots,Y_n $ are i.i.d $N(0,\sigma^2)$, which completes the proof.

---

The following simulation for $n=3,4,5,10$ compares $(2)$ with the pdf of $Z$ in the original post:

[image]

`R` code for the individual plots above:

```
t=rt(1e5,n-2)
z=(n-1)*t/sqrt(n*(t^2+n-2))
hist(z,prob=TRUE,nclass=145,col="wheat")
c=(sqrt(n)*gamma((n-1)/2))/(sqrt(pi)*(n-1)*gamma((n-2)/2))
pdf=function(x){c*(1-n*x^2/(n-1)^2)^(n/2-2)*(abs(x)<(n-1)/sqrt(n))}
curve(pdf,add=TRUE,col="sienna",lwd=3)
```

Comment: why this is true? $(n-1)S^2-\frac{n}{n-1}(X_1-\overline X)^2=\sum_{i=3}^n Y_i^2\,,$

Comment: @Jackie Since$(n-1)S^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2-n\bar{X}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i^2 - Y_1^2=\sum_{i=2}^{n}Y_i^2$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution method somewhat like the second one in the link shared by @StubbornAtom. It is, however, ultimately, different, and for reference, here is the outline.

Let $U = \frac{X_1 - \bar{X}}{S}$, $\hat{X} = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=2}^n X_i$, $\hat{S}^2 = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=2}^n (X_i - \hat{X})^2$. Then $X_1$, $\hat{X}$, and $\hat{S}^2$ are independent (since $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{S}^2$ are the sample mean and scaled sample variance for $X_2, \ldots, X_n$), and $\hat{X} \sim N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1})$, $\hat{S}^2 \sim \chi_{n-1}$. Then, by a calculation

$\begin{equation}
  U = \frac{\frac{n-1}{n}(X_1 - \hat{X})}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}(X_1 - \hat{X})^2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1} \hat{S}^2}} = \varphi(X_1, \hat{X}, \hat{S}^2).
\end{equation}$

Use the transformation $\Phi(x,y,z) = (\varphi(x,y,z),y,z)$ and the usual transformation law with $\Phi^{-1}$ and its Jacobian to obtain the joint density of $U$, $\hat{X}$, and $\hat{S}^2$. Then, FIRST integrate out $\hat{X}$, THEN $\hat{S}^2$, to get the marginal density of $U$. The calculations are brutally tedious, and I actually encourage everyone to skip this exercise, unless they are of the masochistic variety (like me).