# Distributions of Normal-related R.V.s

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If $X_1...X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then we know that $\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Also, if $\overline{X} = \sum X_i/n$ and $S^2 = \frac{\sum (X_i - \overline{X})^2}{n-1}$, then we know that:

(i) $\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

(ii) $\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}} \sim t_{n-1}$

(iii) $\sum (X_i - \mu)^2/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_n$

(iv) $\frac{S^2(n-1)}{\sigma^2} = \sum (X_i - \overline{X})^2/\sigma^2\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$

What can we say about the distributions of the other sensible combinations:

(v) $(X_i - \overline{X})/S$ (i.e. estimating mean and variance with sample mean and variance)

(vi) $\sum (X_i - \overline{X})^2/S^2$ (i.e. estimating the variance with the sample variance)

Comment: For the last, it is const $n-1$ by the definition of $S^2$. For $(X_i - \bar X) / S$, (maybe you mean $\sum (X_i - \bar X)/S$? But this vanishes)

Comment: Right, the last one makes sense - oops. But why is (v) problematic how it is?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4291109/321264